# Erase duplicate emails

Tags: python, regex, email, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to use regex in scrapy to find all email addresses on a page.

I'm using this code:

```
    item["email"] = re.findall('[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body)
```

Which works almost perfectly: it grabs all the emails and gives them to me. However what I want is this: that it doesn't give me a repeat before it actually parses, even if there are more than one of the same email address.

I'm getting responses like this (which is correct):

```
{'email': ['billy666@stanford.edu',
           'cantorfamilies@stanford.edu',
           'cantorfamilies@stanford.edu',
           'cantorfamilies@stanford.edu',
           'footer-stanford-logo@2x.png']}
```

However I want to only show the unique addresses which would be

```
{'email': ['billy666@stanford.edu',
           'cantorfamilies@stanford.edu',
           'footer-stanford-logo@2x.png']}
```

If you want to throw in how to only collect the email and not that

```
'footer-stanford-logo@2x.png'
```

that is helpful also.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why are you using a regex to parse the response? Seems like it might be better suited to an xpath or css selector. Parsing HTML with a regex is usually a bad idea

Comment: Because this is being used In a broad crawler where the data would be stored in different places. So no an xpath wouldnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get rid of the dupes and  `'footer-stanford-logo@2x.png'`-like thingies in your output:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'[\w.-]+@(?![\w.-]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)\b)[\w.-]+\b')
test_str = "{'email': ['billy666@stanford.edu',\n           'cantorfamilies@stanford.edu',\n           'cantorfamilies@stanford.edu',\n           'cantorfamilies@stanford.edu',\n           'footer-stanford-logo@2x.png']}"
print(set(p.findall(test_str)))
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/KwrjbH)

The regex will look like

```
[\w.-]+@(?![\w.-]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)\b)[\w.-]+\b
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO2aB1/1)

The negative lookahead `(?![\w.-]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)\b)` will disallow all matches with `png`, `jpg`, etc. extensions at the end of the *word* (`\b` is a word boundary, and in this case, it is a *trailing* word boundary).

Dupes can easily be removed with a `set` - it is the least troublesome part here.

**FINAL SOLUTION**:

```
item["email"] = set(re.findall(r'[\w.-]+@(?![\w.-]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)\b)[\w.-]+\b', response.body))
```

Comment: Nice touch with the `(?:png|jpe?g|gif)`

Comment: Not sure why but when I use this code it doesnt give any emails but it works with just             item["email"] = set(re.findall('[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body)) which deletes duplicates. Although i'm very interested to know why it doesnt show in my results. Since I followed that demo page (AWESOME BTW) and it worked as expected :/

Comment: Sorry, I have added `r` prefix to mark the string a raw string literal. Now, `\b` is treated as a word boundary, not as a backspace character. Use `item["email"] = set(re.findall(r'[\w.-]+@(?![\w.-]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)\b)[\w.-]+\b', response.body))`

Comment: Got it! Thanks man!!!!! Good to know how that r affected it. Thank you for also explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

```
item["email"] = set(re.findall('[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body))
```

Comment: extra brownie points to ignore that `'footer-stanford-logo@2x.png'`. :) +1 though

Comment: No need to escape a `.` inside a character class. And it really does not help ingore those PNGs. If this one or Thomas' is accepted, the question would be a dupe of [Returning unique matches using regex in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083145/returning-unique-matches-using-regex-in-python). @idjaw: check my answer where I suggest a way to ignore PNGs.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor and if it is a Dupe I'm very sorry i dont fully understand regex so if it was answered I apologize I must not have understood

Comment: Also not exactly sure 
And for the . part I had got this "section" of the code from someone on SO so if its incorrect then thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a set instead of a list?

```
item["email"] = set(re.findall('[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body))
```

And if you really want a list then:

```
item["email"] = list(set(re.findall('[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body)))
```